# Is it possible to get value of an index with ArrayList<Comparable>?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a homework assignment in which I have to complete certain method stubs from an already started project. One of the methods I had to complete was a "Bubble Sorting" algorithm. My code:

```
public void bubbleSort(ArrayList <Comparable> list){
// O(n^2) (quadratic sorting algorithm)
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size() - 1; j++){
            if(list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(j + 1)) > 0){
                int temp = list.get(j);// this says "required int found java.lang.Comparable"
                list.set(j, list.get(j + 1));
                list.set(j + 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because the parameter is `<Comparable>` I cannot do the usual `int temp = list.get(j);` as I would be able to do with `ArrayList<Integer>`. I would change the `<Comparable>` to `<Integer>` (and then also modify the `.compareTo()` section) but I want to complete the assignment with what was given. Basically how can I get the value of the index `j`?

Comment: @BrianRoach but this is how the project was given to me. In order to get full credit I must simply fill out what was asked of me as it was especially designed this way by my teacher.

Comment: Hmm, actually, I take that back, I think I misunderstood what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're thinking you need to know what is *inside* the `Comparable`. You don't. The `compareTo()` method you're using which is defined by that interface tells you everything you need to know, which is the point. This way your sort can sort *anything* that implements that interface. You just need to move the `Comparable`.

Instead of:

```
int temp = list.get(j);
```

You need:

```
Comparable temp = list.get(j);
```

If you look at the [JavaDoc for Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) you'll note that it implements the `Comparable` interface, so you are able to call your sort as:

```
bubbleSort(myList);
```

where `myList` is declared as:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList;
```

Also worth noting ... it really should be:

```
public void bubbleSort(List<Comparable>) {
```

Rather than the specific `ArrayList` - that way any type of `List` can be passed in.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if (list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(j + 1)) > 0) {
  Comparable temp = list.get(j);
  list.set(j, list.get(j + 1));
  list.set(j + 1, temp);
}
```